# Why do routes with a dot in a parameter fail to match?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've got an route for my users like `/iGEL/contributions`, which works fine. But now a user registered with a name like 'A.and.B.', and now the route fails to match, since the name contains dots.

My route:

```
get "/:user/contributions" => 'users#contributions'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

See the blue info box [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-constraints):

> By default dynamic segments don’t
>   accept dots – this is because the dot
>   is used as a separator for formatted
>   routes. If you need to use a dot
>   within a dynamic segment add a
>   constraint which overrides this – for
>   example `:id => /[^\/]+/` allows
>   anything except a slash.

That would for example be:

```
get "/:user/contributions" => 'users#contributions', :constraints => { :user => /[^\/]+/ }
```

Comment: Thanks. The regexp you quoted has a typo thought, it should be /[^\/]+/, not /[^\/]/+. But thats an error in the original guide.

Comment: The syntax would be, for example:
get "/:user/contributions" => 'users#contributions', :constraints => {:id => /[^\/]+/}

Comment: `/.*/` also works, I don't know regex well enough to tell the difference.

Comment: got more details @RyanGlen ? it does work on the indicated ruby on rails versio.

Comment: In Rails 6 I [had to set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57895695/27358) `format: false, defaults: {format: 'html'}` to get Rails to stop trying to treat the dot segment as a file extension indicating a content type.

Answer (score 9):

If your variable segment is the last one, then using the `[^\/]` regex will also eat the format. In such a case rather use:

```
/([^\/]+?)(?=\.json|\.html|$|\/)/
```

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the following link answers your question.

http://avdi.org/devblog/2010/06/18/rails-3-resource-routes-with-dots-or-how-to-make-a-ruby-developer-go-a-little-bit-insane/