# Routing in Rails. Dots in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing

I have overwritten `to_param` method in my `Category` model

```
def to_param
  name
end
```

And `routes.rb`

```
get '/:id' => 'categories#show', :as => :category
```

When `name` parameter doesn't contain any dots (`foobar`), all works right, but when it does (`f.o.o.b.a.r`)
I get an error `No route matches [GET]`. So my question is: is it possible to use dots in routing like a part of name of parameter? Or what can I do to accomplish this purpose, maybe some hooks or something. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can change the constraints for this route:

```
get ':/id' => "categories#show", :as => :category, :constraints => { :id => /[\w+\.]+/ }
```

This route will now match `:id` to any string containing any word character or a dot.

Comment: I don't see how this is a solution.  It breaks if there are non word characters in the URL, which is likely to have at least an '%' and you must at least have 1 dot.  It's like curing a headache by chopping the head off. This is the right solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369654/why-do-routes-with-a-dot-in-a-parameter-fail-to-match