# Rails custom route with parameters not working - No route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am trying to create a custom route that indexes `reviews` by a scope of `shop_id`

I have this in my *routes.rb*:

```
get '/reviews/:shop_id'   => 'reviews#index',         :as => :reviews
```

And this output from my rake routes:

```
reviews GET    /reviews/:shop_id(.:format)       reviews#index
```

And just to be complete, here is my `ReviewsController`:

```
class ReviewsController < BaseController
  def index
    @shop = Shop.find params[:shop_id]
    @reviews = @shop.reviews.all
  end
end
```

When I try to load `http://testshop.dev:3000/reviews/2` I get this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/reviews/2"
```

Why? And how do I fix it?

Comment: How does the basic routing for reviews look like? Doesn't this form get into naming issues with the custom show?

Comment: There's no other routing for reviews

Comment: i tried a similar setup and it seemed to work for me, could you paste your complete routes file (only the lines that are not commented of course)

Comment: try [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718093/routing-in-rails-dots-in-url][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718093/routing-in-rails-dots-in-url

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a completely different reason. I had a basic `form_tag`which had a `/forgot-password` action.

I was missing the leading `/`, so when the form submitted, it'd point to: `/forgot-password/forgot-password`, messing up the `/forgot-password/:attribute` in my route!