# Rails Dot in Url with two routes for one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm making a site with one controller "Projects" and i want to show all projects with to routes :

- /admin/projects/:id = /admin/projects/1 (works)
- /front/:id = /front.1 (doesn't work)

I have tried this

```
get 'front/:id' => 'projects#show', :constraints => { :id => /[^/]+/ }
```

in route.rb but it doesn't work.

My files :

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :users, path: '/admin/clients'

  get 'admin' => 'admin#dashbord'

  get 'admin/profile'

  get 'admin/settings'

  get 'admin/_admin_header'

  get 'front' => 'front#index'

  get 'front/profile' => 'front#profile'

  get 'front/:id' => 'projects#show'

  scope '/admin' do
    resources :projects do
      resources :pictures
    end
  end

  end
```

projects_controller.rb

```
  layout 'adminApplication'
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end


  def show
  end


  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url, notice: 'Project was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end


    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name, :date, :location, :integer)
    end
end
```

front_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
    render 'projects/index'
  end

  def show
  end

  def profile
  end
end
```

in projects/index.html.erb

```
- link_to 'Show', project
- link_to 'Show', front_path(project)
```

I already checked all similar questions.

Thanks for your help !

Kazei Design

---

**Update**

`rake routes | grep front`:

```
           front GET    /front(.:format)             front#index
   front_profile GET    /front/profile(.:format)     front#profile
                 GET    /front/:id(.:format)         projects#show
```

Comment: There should be `:constraints => { :user => /[^\/]+/ }`

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev : thanks for your answer but like i said, i already tried this solution and it doesn't work.

Comment: Just in your code there is `:constraints => { :id => /[^/]+/ }` . Maybe you misspelled but check carefully `/[^/]+/` vs `/[^\/]+/`

Comment: I write this : `get 'front/:id' => 'projects#show', :constraints => { :id => /[^\/]+/ }` and after `rake routes` but it doesn't work...

Comment: You might want to reorder your `routes.rb` file. Write `get 'front/profile' => 'front#profile'` before `get 'front/:id' => 'projects#show'`

Comment: @RohitJangid: thanks for your answer. I reorder my routes.rb but i still have the problem.

Comment: Is this link helping http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718093/routing-in-rails-dots-in-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a *named route helper*, but you didn't specify it:

```
- link_to 'Show', front_path(project)
```

And you can see in your routes that `front_path` for `projects#show` doesn't exist:

```
rake routes | grep front
           front    GET    /front(.:format)                            front#index
   front_profile    GET    /front/profile(.:format)                    front#profile
                    GET    /front/:id(.:format)                        projects#show
```

So, in your `routes.rb` add the helper:

```
get 'front/:id' => 'projects#show', as: :custom_front
```

And now run `rake routes` to see the new helper (it should be `custom_front_path`) and use it:

```
- link_to 'Show', custom_front_path(project)
```

See more info in the [documentation - 4.3 Overriding the Named Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change your route to

```
get 'front.:id' => 'projects#show'
```

Comment: @RohitJangrid: thanks again, but it doesn't change the '.' to '/' . But if i change it myself in the url, it works...