# Rails routing send string with dots and int

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm new to rails...

I try to send such string as :search param: "55.675155, 21.833466" and 2 as :id param...
But something is bad...

i get No route matches [GET] "/exchanger_lists/get_exchangers_via_coordinates/.....

My route file:

```
  match 'exchanger_lists/get_exchangers_via_coordinates/:search,:id' => 'exchanger_lists#get_exchangers_via_coordinates'
```

But also how then url must look in browser???

How to do this in Rails way? I read doc's, but something is not clear on 100% (

Just how to configure my route and how to call from browser?

Comment: Do you have exchanger_lists controller with method get_exchangers_via_coordinates?. Try slash instead of comma: `:search/:id` I don't know is that's a problem but a comma there is not standard inside an URL

Comment: @juanpastas yes i have, all is ok working if i pass in url something like exchanger_lists/get_exchangers_via_coordinates/535,1    but with string (dots, comma) is bad. Also your solution didn't help

Comment: maybe this could help you: http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/06/18/rails-3-resource-routes-with-dots-or-how-to-make-a-ruby-developer-go-a-little-bit-insane/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
match 'exchanger_lists/get_exchangers_via_coordinates/:search,:id' => 'exchanger_lists#get_exchangers_via_coordinates', 
constraints: { search: /[^\/]+/ }
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369654/why-do-routes-with-a-dot-in-a-parameter-fail-to-match)

Comment: just i change to 'exchanger_lists/get_exchangers_via_coordinates/:search/:distance'        all is ok, but when i try to send distance as float (for example 0.5) something is bad...

Comment: do the same for distance `constraints: { search: /[^\/]+/, distance: /[^\/]+/ }`

Comment: heh, wait.... but how to be if i call a json view? if i write .... .json it didn't understand

Comment: maybe something like? distance: /[^\/]+(?=\.html\z|\.json\z)/      but how to be when .html is by default not writen? if empty - then html, if added .json then json

Comment: You have to write a regexp that matches `5.5` in `5.5.json` `/[^\/]+?(?!.*..json)/`. I could not understand that regexp :p

Comment: is not working as must do.... Look: .html - could be, but could be empty(than render html page), but also i could have .json (then render json). Now your /[^\/]+?(?!.*..json)/ is working strange)) if i enter /53.674239,%2023.828101/0.1  i get nothing(invalid param is getting to method), but if write /53.674239,%2023.828101/0.1.html all is ok, also with json all is ok

Comment: You should ask for a regular expression in another question, that one was difficult for me. for `5.5` should match `5.5` for `5.5.(json|html)` should match `5.5`

Answer (score 0):

You could change your routes like following:

```
 match 'exchanger_lists/get_exchangers_via_coordinates/:x/:y/:id' => 'exchanger_lists#get_exchangers_via_coordinates'
```

params[:x] and params[:y] will hold your coordinates. I think this is more beautiful code, than holding the to coordinates in one param.

Comment: i need to pass it as one param! that's the problem   coordinates - one param

Comment: man) i get this params from other mobile app, which i didn't develop, only use