# Rails send email via GET

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a route setup:

```
get 'e/:email' => "static#home"
```

So in the controller I want to get the email via `params[:email]`

Somehow this won't work, as I open the URL it says:

```
No route matches [GET] "/e/test%40gmail.com"
```

How would you accomplish this? Cheers!

Comment: You seem to be missing a double quote in your route.

Comment: thanks, was a typo when copying

Comment: Maybe you have another route defined above that one that's overriding it?

Comment: nope, I explicitly added the `e/` so that it wouldn't override another route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
get 'e/:email' => "static#home", :format => false, :constraints => { :email => /[^\/]+/ }
```

#### Explanation:

By default, rails won't allow a `.` in a parameter.

I just tried implementing an equivalent route in my own rails app, and it worked. The params hash looked like this:

```
{"controller"=>"pages", "action"=>"home", "email"=>"test@gmail", "format"=>"com"}
```

The reason it still worked for me is that by default, rails assumes anything after the `.` is the format parameter (the format param is normally used, eg, to specify that you want json - eg. `example.com/my_controller/index.json`).

Since you're getting the error, you must have things set up to ignore that `format` parameter that is included by default.

So, you should be able to reproduce the result I got (ie, a matching route, but with the `.com` part in the `format` param, not the `email` param) with the following:

```
get 'e/:email' => "static#home", :format => true
```

But to solve your problem, and continue to exclude `format` param, but to include the `.`, and everything after it, as part of your `email` param, you need to pass through that last option, `:constraints => { :email => /[^\/]+/ }` which basically says to allow anything but a slash in the email param.

More info here: [Why do routes with a dot in a parameter fail to match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369654/why-do-routes-with-a-dot-in-a-parameter-fail-to-match)

Comment: thanks! Great in depth answer, helped me out plenty :)