# How to write right route with Rails about the dot character in the url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `config/routes.rb` file, I created a nested resource as follows:

```
resources :tags, only: [] do
  resources :blogs, only: [:index]
end
```

The problem is, if I create a tag named `node.js`, when I access the page by:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/tags/node.js/blogs
```

I get a routing error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/tags/node.js/blogs"
```

How do I get routing to work properly for resources with a dot in the name?

Comment: Could you rune `bin/rake routes` and find if the route exists, something like `tags/:id/blogs`

Comment: Add this: `constraints: { id: /[^\/]+/ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369702

The dot (.) Is normally use to separate

That would for example be:

```
get "/:user/contributions" => 'users#contributions', :constraints => { :user => /[^\/]+/ }
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Rails Routing from the Outside In, section 3.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

> By default, dynamic segments don't accept dots - this is because the
>   dot is used as a separator for formatted routes. If you need to use a
>   dot within a dynamic segment, add a constraint that overrides this –
>   for example, id: /[^/]+/ allows anything except a slash.

Therefore, make your route like this:

```
resources :tags, only: [], id: /[^\/]+/ do
  resources :blogs, only: [:index], id: /[^\/]+/ 
end
```

Comment: Thank you. But should add `id: /[^\/]+/ ` after `tags`