# Having a period (.) in url throws Model.nil error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

Using Rails, I have a model "User", for which the action "Show" routes to `users/:name`. Usually it works fine, except that when there's a period (.) in the name, the server can no longer find the record. For example, `http/localhost:3000/Joe%20Jr.`.

How can I fix this?

**routes.rb:**

```
get 'users/:name', to: "users#show", as: 'user'
get 'users/:id/edit', to: "users#edit", as: "edit_user"
resources :users
```

**users_controller.rb:**

```
def create
  #...
  redirect_to user_path
end
```

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369654/why-do-routes-with-a-dot-in-a-parameter-fail-to-match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try your route as

```
get 'users/:name', to: 'user#show', as: 'user', constraints: { name: /.*/ }
```

This got us around the same problem.

Credit to Avdi Grimm's blog post "[Rails 3 resource routes with dots; or, how to make a Ruby developer go a little bit insane](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/06/18/rails-3-resource-routes-with-dots-or-how-to-make-a-ruby-developer-go-a-little-bit-insane/)".

Comment: a small typo in the constraint there, should be `name` right instead of `fname`

Comment: Oliver, your right. I copied from our code without a close check. Should be fixed.

Comment: With this code, 'users/:name' works, but now 'users/:id/edit' is returning a "record not found" error. Any idea why, or how I can fix that? I added that route to my question.

Comment: Wait a second, the error is actually coming from Users#show! Why would Users#edit suddenly be using code from Users#show?

Comment: Might help to see more code, but in your using :id and not :name in the edit route.

Comment: @RobOlendorf Is there a way I can use :id for edit and :name for show?

Comment: Should be able to do that in your controller, something like User.find(params[:id]), but I would strongly recommend consistency for your long term sanity.