# Ruby on Rails - Route not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a CommunitiesSearchController with a search method.

I defined its route like this:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    namespace :v1 do          
      resources :communities
      get 'community/search/coordinates/:latitude/:longitude', to: 'communities_search#search'
    end
  end
```

But when I try to access it:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/community/search
/coordinates/49.2864807/-123.142214"):
```

I'm using rails 5.

rails routes command:

```
                  api_v1 GET      /api/v1/community/search/coordinates/:latitude
/:longitude(.:format) api/v1/communities_search#search {:format=>"json"}
```

**SOLUTION** Please view:

[Why do routes with a dot in a parameter fail to match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369654/why-do-routes-with-a-dot-in-a-parameter-fail-to-match)

Comment: `rake routes` should be your go-to.

Comment: It seems the call is for `/api/v1/...` but your configuration is not for that.  As @meagar mentioned, `rake routes` will help.

Comment: It is on the routes !

Comment: Yes meagar, you are right. The solution was on the other post. Sorry for this!