# Handling html extension as slug in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem in my current API. Android app have app link, I get `get_post/slug.html.json` from Android app, that make a `no route matches` in API application. I can't fix it in Android app because already on play store to remove `.html`.

How can I handle it in routes? so my route can ignore `.html` extension and make `.html` as slug, so I can remove `.html` in controller before query to database

Comment: can you provide more info related to that "app link"? some code would be great

Comment: What you have in params on this request? And what is in your routes (related to the request)?

Comment: @Getu i can't, I only have access to backend code.. app link handle in android app https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/, backend only get request from android about detail of post by slug, which is in route i have something like this `get 'get_post/:slug', to: 'posts#detail'`. I found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369702/2858044, i think that related with my problem