# Suppress file extension detection / format mapping in Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I have a Rails route of the form

```rb
get '/:collection/*files' => 'player#index'
```

where `files` is intended to be a semicolon-separated list of media files, e.g. `/my-collection/some-video.mp4%3Bsome-audio.mp3`

These are handled by a controller action of the form:

```
class PlayerController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @collection = params[:collection]
    @files = params[:files].split(';')
  end
end
```

and rendered with a template that displays an HTML5 `<audio>` or `<video>` element for each file.

This works fine so long as the files have no extension, e.g.
`/my-collection/file1%3Bfile2`.

However, if I add the file extensions,
`/my-collection/foo.mp3%3Bbar.mp4`,
I get:

> **No route matches [GET] "/my-collection/foo.mp3%3Bbar.mp4"**

And if I try it with a single file, e.g. `/my-collection/foo.mp3`, I get:

> **PlayerController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["audio/mpeg"] request.variant: []**

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369702/27358) I added a regex constraint to the route:

```rb
  get '/:collection/*files' => 'player#index', constraints: {files: /[^\/]+/}
```

This solves the **No route matches** problem, but now the multiple, separated version also fails with **missing a template**. (It's not ideal anyway, since I'd still rather allow `/` in file values. But `/.*/` didn't work any better.)

I tried `format: false`, with and without `constraints`, and still got **missing a template**.

I also tried an ordinary path parameter (`/:collection/:files`), and got the same behavior as for the wildcard `*files`.

How can I get Rails to ignore and pass through the extension for this route?

---

**Note:** I'm using Rails 6.0.0 on Ruby 2.5.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the discussion on [this Rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28901#issuecomment-297747521), the magic formula appears to be adding `defaults: {format: 'html'}` to `format: false`:

```rb
  get '/:collection/:files',
      to: 'player#index',
      format: false,
      defaults: {format: 'html'},
      constraints: {files: /.*/}
```